# angular ui router named view state overriding another named view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a project with 2 ui-view div:

```
<div ui-view='agent-station'></div>
<div ui-view='routingConfig'></div>
```

The main state login is successfully loaded in both:

```
$stateProvider
    .state("login", {
      url: "/login",
      views: {
        'agent-station': {
          templateUrl: "login.html"
        },
        'routingConfig': {
          templateUrl: "loginrc.html"
        }
      }
    })
```

The problem arises when I click in one link which URL updates only one of the ui-views. The ui-view referenced by that URL is successfully updated, but the other ui-view becomes blank. So for example if I click on Test 1 AG link on the plunker example the Test 1 Agent station state is updated but the Login Routing Config state becomes a blank page.

My main suspicion is the following line:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
```

But I'm not sure why it becomes blank instead of showing the login page for Routing Config ui-view.

What could be the problem?

Here is my plunker:

[Angular Named Views Test](https://plnkr.co/edit/jn4nZN0hm5C0fzXP5mza?p=preview)

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve? If one clicks on test1ag and afterwards on test2rc what should be displayed? If your goal is to display the test1ag and the test2rc contents then, this could become somehow complicated (9 or even 16 combos). Think of how the routing should determine the chosen templates when you enter the url directly. "test2rc" has no information about the contents selected before. On the other side, if you want to fall back to some default state for AG when having selected a special RC, then there is an easy way of inheritance to do this. What is your goal?

Comment: "If one clicks on test1ag and afterwards on test2rc what should be displayed?" It should display "Test1 Agent station" on agent-station ui-view and login routing config on routingConfig ui-view and afterwards when test2rc is clicked is should maintain agent-station ui-view state and show "Test2 Routing Config" on routingConfig ui-view. I understand this is tricky but I have no other way to do this as my web apps are under a container with 2 tabs, one will show the agent station and the other tab will show the routing config. It currently overrides the ui-view from one tab to the other. Thanks!

Comment: I assume this is a hard task for the angular 1 ui router. There is a concept of auxiliary routes in the angular 2 router that handles such a special case. When you design your states, always consider that the router needs to be able to render your state from the information in the url alone. So you would need some `test1ag-test2rc`-style states to cover that, which gets pretty ugly with more than 2x2 combos...

Comment: And this is just the simple requirement, the final one will be with 3 apps so it will become ugly and unmaintenable :-(

Comment: I finally got it working, probably not the best way to fix it but created 3 modules 1 per app: appPDA, appRouting, appHist. I copied angular-ui-router.min.js under each of these apps js folder and renamed module name from ui.router to pda.ui.router, routing.ui.router, hist.ui.router.

I injected each of these *.ui.router module names for each of my modules and got it working. Now navigation is independent of course by using named views and diferent urls, state names on each of this modules' config file.

Hope this helps anybody